# ¿alguien puede componer mi código de mi aplicación intento almacenar datos, pero no me deja la id es auto incrementable, y la fecha es timestamp?

Tags: android, xampp

**alguien puedo componer mi código la id es auto incrementable y la fecha la tengo con time stamp
y no se porque no inserta los datos, todavía no almacena y no doy en donde esta el error ya que no me marca nada solo hace que si envió el registro y nada, si pudieran componer mi código por favor ya que no se casi nada y ya no se que mas hacer para que funcione el código**

**estos son mis pH**
**conexión**

```
 <?php
    $hostname='localhost';
    $database='proyecto';
    $username='root';
    $password='';
    
    $conexion = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
    if($conexion->connect_error){
        echo "no funciona";
    }
    ?>
```

**buscar**

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

$id=$_GET['id'];

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM visitantes WHERE id='$id'";

$resultado = $conexion ->query($consulta);

while($fila=$resultado->fetch_array()){

    $visitantes[] = array_map('utf8_decode',$fila);

}

echo  json_encode($visitantes)

$resultado->close();

?>
```

**insertar**

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apellidoP=$_POST['apellidoP'];
$apellidoM=$_POST['apellidoM'];
$direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$genero =$_POST['genero'];
$curp=$_POST['curp'];
$asunto =$_POST['asunto'];

$consulta="insert into visitantes values('".$nombre."','".$apellidoP."','".$apellidoM."','".$direccion."','".$telefono."',,'".$genero."','".$curp."','".$asunto."')";
mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close();
?>
```

**mi clase java en android aqui hago uso de los metodos pero no me funciona para el almacenado**

```
public class QRVisitante extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText id, nombre, apellidoP, apellidoM, direccion, telefono, sexo, curp, asunto;
    Button ingresar, btnBuscar, limpiar;

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_q_r_visitante);

        id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
        nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        apellidoP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.apellidoP);
        apellidoM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dapellidoM);
        direccion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.direccion);
        telefono = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefono);
        sexo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sexo);
        curp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.curp);
        asunto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.asunto);
        ingresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ingresar);

        btnBuscar =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);
       limpiar =(Button)findViewById(R.id.limpiar);

        limpiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                id.setText("");
                nombre.setText("");
                apellidoP.setText("");
                apellidoM.setText("");
                direccion.setText("");
                telefono.setText("");
                sexo.setText("");
                curp.setText("");
                asunto.setText("");
            }
        });


        ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ejecutarservicio("http://192.168.1.109:80/proyecto/insertar.php");
            }
        });

        btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buscar("http://192.168.1.109:80/proyecto/buscar.php?id="+id.getText()+"");
            }
        });

    }

    private void ejecutarservicio(String URL) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new  Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("id", id.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("nombre", nombre.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("apellidoP", apellidoP.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("apellidoM", apellidoM.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("direccion", direccion.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("telefono", telefono.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("sexo", sexo.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("curp", curp.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("asunto", asunto.getText().toString());
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void buscar(String URL){
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        nombre.setText(jsonObject.getString("nombre"));
                        apellidoP.setText(jsonObject.getString("apellidoP"));
                        apellidoM.setText(jsonObject.getString("apellidoM"));
                        direccion.setText(jsonObject.getString("direccion"));
                        telefono.setText(jsonObject.getString("telefono"));
                        sexo.setText(jsonObject.getString("sexo"));
                        curp.setText(jsonObject.getString("curp"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        );
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

**no se como puedo que inserte el la tabla de la base de datos alguien me puede ayudar con eso**
**ya busque pero no en cuentero como darle solución**
**alguien que sepa del tema y pueda componer mi código se lo agradecería mucho ya que estoy batallando con esto**

Comment: Que se muestra en el LogCat? en onErrorResponse() se obtiene algo?

Comment: no marca nada error al mandar los datos me dice que se envió pero nada, solo cuando busco los datos por la id

Answer (score 0):

tienes problemas en tu consulta de insertar debería ser así

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...);
```

estas solo declarando los valores a insertar sin las columnas que corresponden los datos

```
$consulta="insert into visitantes (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES('".$nombre."','".$apellidoP."','".$apellidoM."','".$direccion."','".$telefono."',,'".$genero."','".$curp."','".$asunto."')";
```